# prints strange numbers from memory

Tags: c++, memory, printing

I have a list(dynamic vector) that contains medicines and I want to print all the medicines from the list but it prints some numbers from memory. For example:

```
Give the medicine's ID: 1
Give the medicine's name:alg
Give the medicine's concentration: 30
Give the medicine's quantity: 40
```

Prints:

```
The medicine's ID is: 4215400
The medicine's name is: 
The medicine's concentration is: 3.47235e+230
The medicine's quantity is: 2686544
```

These are the print functions:

```
 void Console::printMedicine(Medicine* m){
        int ID = m->getID();
        string name = m->getName();
        double concentration = m->getConcentration();
        int quantity = m->getQuantity();
        cout<<"\nThe medicine's ID is: "<<ID<<"\n";
        cout<<"The medicine's name is: "<<name<<"\n";
        cout<<"The medicine's concentration is: "<<concentration<<"\n";
        cout<<"The medicine's quantity is: "<<quantity<<"\n";
    }

    void Console::printAllMedicines(){
        DynamicVector<Medicine*>* medList = ctrl->getAllMeds();
        for(int i=0; i < medList->getLen(); i++){
            Medicine* m = medList->getElementAtPosition(i);
            printMedicine(m);
        }
    }
```

This is the getElementAtPosition function:

```
template <typename Element>
Element DynamicVector<Element>::getElementAtPosition(int pos){
    return this->elems[pos];
}
```

this is the medicine class, only the private part:

```
class Medicine{
private:
    int ID, quantity;
    double concentration;
    string name;
```

and this is the declaration of medList in repository:

```
class Repository{
    public:
        DynamicVector<Medicine*>* medList;
```

constructor and getters in the medicine class:

```
  Medicine::Medicine(){ //implicit constructor
        this->ID=0;
        this->concentration=0;
        this->name="";
        this->quantity=0;
    }

    Medicine::Medicine(int ID, string name, double concentration, int quantity){ //constructor with parameters
        this->ID=ID;
        this->name=name;
        this->concentration=concentration;
        this->quantity=quantity;


int Medicine::getID(){
    return this->ID;
}

string Medicine::getName(){
    return this->name;
}

double Medicine::getConcentration(){
    return this->concentration;
}

int Medicine::getQuantity(){
    return this->quantity;

        }
```

the getAllMeds and getAll functions:

```
DynamicVector<Medicine*>* Controller::getAllMeds(){
    return repo->getAll();
}

DynamicVector<Medicine*>* Repository::getAll(){
    return medList;
}
```

I tried some hours to fix this but I just can't understand where's the problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is where a debugger would come in really handy.

Comment: Can we see the constructor and `get*()` functions of the `Medicine` class?

Comment: Unless it's for something like schoolwork, why create your own vector when there is [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: the code mentioned here doesn't shows the whole picture of all the memory allocation and objects creation. this looks like a simple issue where objects are not properly updated. just get a good debugger and you will surely find it.

Comment: How do you _add_ items to your list? Are you perhaps putting pointers to local variables in it?

Comment: Where you going wrong is 1) using way too many pointers and 2) Not using std::vector. Fix those two problems and it will be a lot easier to fix any remaining problems. Probably not very helpful but it's the best I can do with the code shown. Basically you have made everything a pointer, and that is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your Medicine instances are created by getAllMeds(). Are you sure you are passing good values into your constructor? Those values you are seeing look like uninitialized memory to me. Are they the same strange values every time or do they change?

Comment: No, they don't change because if I add the second medicine and try to print the 2 medicines, the program crashes

Comment: The thing I need to see is the place where you are instantiating your Medicine class. I want to see what you are passing into the Medicine constructor. I think that must be where the problem is.